# Django how to deploy css and javascript

Tags: javascript, django, minify

What the best way to organize and deploy java-script and css files in django ? The main idea is rather simple - in debug mode use a lot of JS's and in production only one minified java-script . I am think that I 'am inventing a bicycle, trying to reorganize my old project this way, and should be some well known solution for this problem.

Seems I have found what I need - django-pipeline

Answer (score 2):

See [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in official documentation.

In short:

- When debugging you can ask Django to serve these files by himself (just put them in one directory and configure `STATICFILES_DIRS`).
- When going into production stage, you should use a real webserver like Apache. (see [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/))

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all static files in a folder (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) and then run requirejs optimiser to minify and merge the js files (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).